# InvalidRegistration error when trying to use Volley to send push notifications over FCM

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-volley

I am trying to send push notifications using Volley to FCM, but they are not received on the other side. The response I am gettin from Volley is this one

```
{"multicast_id":7351526324257141941,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

I am new to FCM and Volley, and have followed [this guide](https://blog.usejournal.com/send-device-to-device-push-notifications-without-server-side-code-238611c143). The idea is that every user subscribes to their uid as a topic, and when a a certain action related to them happens (someone likes their photo for example) then a message would be sent with the topic as their ID.

Whenever the user logs in to the app I execute the follwong code:

```
val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid
val userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users/$uid/services/firebase-token")
userRef.setValue(token)
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(uid)
```

I am currently in the testing, so the message I am trying to send is pretty generic. These are the functions that should execute it.

```
static void sendMessageTopic(String receiverId, String initiatorId, String post, Activity activity) {

        String NOTIFICATION_TITLE = "some title";

        String NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE = "This is the message";


        JSONObject notification = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject notificationBody = new JSONObject();
        try {
            notificationBody.put("title", NOTIFICATION_TITLE);
            notificationBody.put("message", NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE);

            notification.put("to", receiverId);
            notification.put("data", notificationBody);
        } catch (
                JSONException e) {
            Log.e("notificationStuff", "onCreate: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        sendNotification(notification, activity);
    }
```

Then:

```
static void sendNotification(JSONObject notification, Activity activity) {

        String FCM_API = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
        String serverKey =
                "AAAAA6gibkM:APA91bG8UUtfNFwNLI6-Peu_KsbpTskmjutdJDyHq-qi5fj2UdCcjIVRCO5PlhZUNfJdeyW4-3oznOxMDWdjpfSAnpltlvtBFCoM_vir7pQLKbxc_aDzWJPs8xu27CADbMkHkq5tKgT7";

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(FCM_API, notification,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.i("notificationStuff", "onResponse: " + response.toString());
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Request error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.i("notificationStuff", "onErrorResponse: Didn't work");
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("Authorization", "key=" + serverKey);
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                return params;
            }
        };
        MySingleton.getInstance(activity.getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
```

The singleton:

```
public class MySingleton {
    private  static MySingleton instance;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private Context ctx;

    private MySingleton(Context context) {
        ctx = context;
        requestQueue = getRequestQueue();
    }

    public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new MySingleton(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (requestQueue == null) {
            // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
            // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ctx.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return requestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }
}
```

And then my method to catch receiving messages:

```
public class MyJavaFCM extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private final String ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID ="admin_channel";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        int notificationID = new Random().nextInt(3000);

      /*
        Apps targeting SDK 26 or above (Android O) must implement notification channels and add its notifications
        to at least one of them. Therefore, confirm if version is Oreo or higher, then setup notification channel
      */
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            setupChannels(notificationManager);
        }

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this , 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.profile_icon);

        Uri notificationSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_fallback)
                .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"))
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(notificationSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        //Set notification color to match your app color template
        notificationBuilder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        notificationManager.notify(notificationID, notificationBuilder.build());
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void setupChannels(NotificationManager notificationManager){
        CharSequence adminChannelName = "New notification";
        String adminChannelDescription = "Device to devie notification";

        NotificationChannel adminChannel;
        adminChannel = new NotificationChannel(ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID, adminChannelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        adminChannel.setDescription(adminChannelDescription);
        adminChannel.enableLights(true);
        adminChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        adminChannel.enableVibration(true);
        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(adminChannel);
        }
    }
}
```

The only indication of what's wrong I get is that message I've adde in the beginning but I'm not quite sure what to make of it (tried to read on it but couldn't understand much of what was said and not sure if it is related to my specific case.

Answer (score 0):

When following the guide, the author wrote the topics destination in a format similar to this `/topics/yourTopic` but I thought this is how it is organized in his database or something like this. I dind't think much of it and didn't copy the `/topics` part to my code, but this is the reason it didn't go through.

I had to change this

```
notification.put("to", receiverId);
```

to this:

```
notification.put("to", "/topics/" + receiverId);
```